# Примеры реализации поиска Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет!

Есть задача по поиску, который должен искать артикулы товара, которые находятся в свойстве
Например, есть артикул 12345, нужно сделать чтобы поиск работал и по 12345 и по 123-45 и по 12-345
И что бы работал по не полному вводу, например если ввести 123, поиск выдаст результат со всеми элементами у которых арткул начинается на 123

Подскажите примеры реализации

Answer (score 0):

То о чем вы пишете уже реализовано в самом модуле "Поиск" системы.

Вам необходимо перейти в административный раздел, и затем `Настройки-Настройки продукта-Настройки модулей-Поиск`, на вкладке `Поиск` поставить галочку у параметра `Использовать быстрый поиск (с ухудшенным ранжированием`. После сохранения нажать кнопку "Переиндексация сайта".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]